# Can Google Cloud Tasks be programmatically deleted using Node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-tasks

According to the [documentation about deleting tasks and queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/deleting-tasks-and-queues#deleting_tasks_from_a_queue), this can be done in Go, Java, Python and PHP. Node is disabled.

Is there a way to do this using Node? I'm already creating Tasks using node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  The link you provided in your question is not what you want to look at.  It's referring to App Engine task queues, which is different than Cloud Tasks.

The nodejs API documentation for Cloud Tasks starts [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/index.html).  You can delete an existing task with [deleteTask](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks.v2.CloudTasks.html#deleteTask1).

I've written a [blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) that discusses in detail the creation and deletion of tasks that implement a TTL for a Firesore document.  It uses deleteTask to cancel the task if needed.